# Way to find out transactions on exchange that shutdown?

Tags: transactions

I have in the past had an account on liqui.io ( which shutdown a few years ago ). I have emails showing the withdrawn actions including the amounts / destination address, but I have no records of deposits.

Any tools to bulk check if a set of addresses made transactions to another set of addresses, or any other ideas how to figure out what trades I may have made on an inactive exchange?